# Handling errors produced by incorrect queries using psycopg2 and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, psycopg2

I have a function that queries a postgres server using psycopg2 and returns a pandas dataframe back.

There are two major issues that can cause the function to fail.

1) the server is down - This gets handled by a psycopg2.OperationalError exception. Which I can use to make the user aware that they should check if the server is up.

2) the user puts in a wrong query.

The second one is what I need help with. I believe this is a DatabaseError. I want to use this as an exception and print out a message to the user to correct their query.

Code example is below:

```
conn = None
query = 'SELECT nonsense from schema1.table'
try:
    conn = pyscopg2.connect(params)
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
except (psycopg2.OperationalError,psycopg2.DatabaseError) as e:
    print (f'Query failed!\n\n{e})
```

With an improper query as above, I would expect the error message to be "Query failed!" and then the error to be shown below that.

Currently I am simply getting:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on query 'SELECT nonsense from schema1.table': column "nonsense" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT nonsense from schema1.table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should/can handle the error on the pandas level.

Handling `pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError` works for me:

```
from pandas.io.sql import DatabaseError 

try:
    # ...
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
except DatabaseError as e:
    print (f'Query failed!\n\n{e}')
```

Comment: This is definitely the right way to go about it. Thanks for the heads up.